# Add To Favourites Functionality

Tags: iphone, favorites

I'm having some trouble getting the add to favourites functionality working.
Here is the code that I'm using to setup the array and dictionary for the favourites data:

In the app delegate, in "appDidFinishLaunching":

```
delegateFavouritesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSLog(@"Mutable Dictionary: %@", delegateFavouritesDictionary);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Saved.data"];

[delegateFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];

delegateFavouritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then in my detailViewController, I have an addToFavourites function:

```
if([[addToFavouritesDictionary allKeys] containsObject:ID]) {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Saved.data"];

    [addToFavouritesDictionary removeObjectForKey:ID];
    [addToFavouritesArray removeObject:Name];
    [favouritesButton setTitle:@"+ Favourites" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    [addToFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
    NSLog(@"New Dictionary: %@", addToFavouritesDictionary);

} else {

    [addToFavouritesArray addObject:Name];
    NSString *ID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ID"];
    [addToFavouritesDictionary setObject:Name forKey:ID];
    [favouritesButton setTitle:@"- Favourites" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Saved.data"];

    [addToFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
    NSLog(@"Mutable Dictionary: %@", addToFavouritesDictionary);
    //[addToFavouritesDictionary release];
}
```

The above code works as expected, on app launch, it sets up a dictionary and loads contents of "Saved.data" into the dictionary, then in the detailViewController, it loads the "Saved.data" file and adds or deletes to that file. The problem I'm having is when the iPhone restarts, all the favorites data is gone, or if the app crashes and is then open again, all the data in the favourites is gone. Is there any way to have the data saved without being deleted everytime the device restarts or is powered off?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see reading from the file anywhere, is it a typo in the question or do you really never read your saved.data file?

Comment: in the detailViewController, I initiate the addToFavouritesDictionary in the viewDidLoad method, I forgot to add that code.

Comment: okay so see my answer, I suppose you are just overwriting your data on each restart. Well, anyway my data doesn't vanish from Documents folder just because my iPhone was turned off so I see no reason why your data should be removed.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I think im going to have to get rid of the addToFavouritesArray, how can I check to see if an object exists in a dictionary instead?

Comment: using objectForKey: method. But you do not have to switch array for dictionary, both can be written to file. Just load it only once in appDidFinishLoading, save on each change or just while leaving the application (applicationDidEnterBackground and/or applicationWillTerminate - the former if you support multitasking and the latter otherwise) and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you store it in user prefs?

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:yourobject forKey:@"yourkey"];
```

Or in SQLite...

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a go, so would you recommend storing the dictionary in user prefs and then loading this in the detailViewController?

Comment: Yes, it is the easyest way i think. Or if you have tonns of favorites, use SQLite.

Comment: Ok thanks, generally the end user would only have up to maybe 15 to 20 favourites, I can't see people having any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you were overwriting you favorites each time your app starts, in appDidFinishLaunching you are creating a new dictionary and saving to saved.data, now if you read it in detailViewController you will get the new empty dictionary.

This would explain why you are using your data if the iPhone restarts, since powering off and on the device doesn't remove your files saved in the Documents directory. This directory is there so that you can save your data and keep it safely between restarts, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense and then it should be called "tmp" which is not.

**EDIT**

Suggestion: load it only once in appDidFinishLoading, save on each change or just while leaving the application (applicationDidEnterBackground and/or applicationWillTerminate - the former if you support multitasking and the latter otherwise) and you should be okay.

**EDIT**

What I do is to use NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver, so save data:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: d toFile: filePath];
```

then to restore:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: filePath];
if (d == nil) {
    d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

You can also try this: `+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` of the NSDictionary class to get a dictionary from a file:

```
delegateFavouritesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
if (delegateFavouritesDictionary == nil) {
    delegateFavouritesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

as you see you don't have to check if the file exists, since in case of any error you will get nil, in which case you would create an empty instance.

Comment: Ok, in appDidFinishLaunching, should I check if the file exists first and if not, create the file, if it does exist just load it?

Comment: only if it haven't been loaded from the file, that's why you do it only if delegateFavouritesDictionary is nil, which is checked using (! delegateFavouritesDictionary). I now think it would be more clear if it were explicitly checked against nil, I have edited the answer.

Comment: so at start you first try to load, if it works you are ready to go and have your previous favorites on board. Otherwise you create an empty dictionary ready to be filled by the application. Now at the proper times (like when exiting the application) you have to save it, to be able to load on the next start.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working unfortunately, in appDidFinishLaunching, I am setting up the file paths for the dictionary and the array, then I archive the files, then I check to see if the dictionary or array is equal to nil (your code above), if they are not nil, I am setting the array = a, and the dictionary = d, I then try to archive these but the app is crashing, any ideas?